# Devise messing with my routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently turned to devise for my authentication routine. However, i'm still having some problems with it and mainly with routing. After a user logs in, i have the routes :

```
  devise_for :users

  namespace :user do
    root :to => "town#index"
  end
```

After i log in, i'm redirected to town controller. There i have this line :

```
<%= link_to raw("<p class='menu_head'>#{t('menu.inventory')}</p>"), :controller => "character" %>
```

This actually worked well with restful authentication, but for devise to work i have to specify the controller as "/character", else i get a :

```
No route matches {:controller=>"user/character"}
```

Though this route is incorrect. How can this be fixed ?

Moreover, i think this one is caused by devise once more. When a new user signs up, devise redirects them to town#index as it would happen if they have logged in. When this happens, for some reason current_user is not initialized. This only happens after sign up not when a user logs in. I'm pretty sure that i'm doing something wrong with devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the routing helpers rather than the options to get to this controller. Define a path helper in your routes file and use that instead. This way, you'll always be given the right URL.

At the moment, your application is sending you to `users/town` because that's what you're telling it to. The URL for sign in is `/users/sign_in` and by passing `:controller` you're saying "go to `/users/town`. If you were using named routes this would not occur.

Comment: I wouldn't really want to use named routes. This is not really the problem. It probably comes from my misconfiguring something with devise. My login procedure starts at home controller and upon successful login, a user is redirected to the town controller, else he stays there. It seems that the devise controller is messing with my controllers and i'm kinda striving to find a way out :/

Comment: @SpyrosP: Please listen to the *years* of experience I have. Using a named route would fix this problem instantly and requires no effort what so ever.

Comment: Hey, absolutely no intention on judging your experience, really. I just wanted to understand why this is happening. I'm sure it works with a named route, i'm doing something like that already as i mention. The thing is, why is the devise controller messing with my controllers.

Comment: Hmm, /users/sign_in is handled by the devise controller. But when i specify town as my controller, why does it mess with devise/town or users/town ? This is a bit weird for me. Anyway, i can use named routes, i don't disagree. But there seem to be more on the way. For instance, current_user is not correct when a user signs in exactly after sign up. It seems to me that this needs a whole different way of handling :/